# Linker error: _main already defined in *.obj

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

The following code structure:

### ArrayStack.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY_STACK_H
#define ARRAY_STACK_H
#include "Array.h"
// class ArrayStack
#endif
```

### ArrayStack.cpp

```
#include "ArrayStack.h"
// ArrayStack's methods
```

### Array.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY_HEADER
#define ARRAY_HEADER
#include <iostream>
// class Array
#endif
```

### Array.cpp

```
#include "Array.h"
// Array's methods
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "ArrayStack.h"
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

generates these errors:

> LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found
>
> LNK2005   _main already defined in Array.obj

**What's the problem here?** Please do note that `Array.cpp` did have `int main()` defined in itself when it was included in the project for the first time, but no longer has it (neither does the `ArrayStack.cpp`). Also, the code compiles just fine when the `int main()` in `main.cpp` is omitted...

Comment: There may be an old object file that contains a main function.  Clean the project so everything gets recompiled.

Comment: @AnonMail I did the 'Clean Solution' option, and even manually deleted the .obj files, but nothing has changed...

Comment: Perhaps the old Array.obj was placed in a library that you are linking against?  Somehow, it's saying it's contained in Array.obj.

Comment: Delete all of the .obj files again. Then open a command prompt, navigate to the root of the solution folder, and use `dir /b /s *.obj` to see what you may have missed. If you missed nothing, I have no answer. Ergo this is a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message means that in all the compiled code, the *.obj files, the linker finds more than one `main()` function. One is obviously in main.cpp.

The first solution that comes to mind, as mentioned in comments, is to (enforce) re-compile by somehow deleting the *.obj files.

When this doesn't change anything try to rebuild your solution separately from scratch. Start with main.cpp without the include. Then successively add files where you are confident that you won't get errors. Maybe you have to comment out some lines in some cases to make compilation possible.

Comment: I've rebuilt it from scratch just before you posted, it seems that the `Array.cpp` file included and `Array.cpp` file in Solution Explorer somehow weren't the same (the one included still had `int main()`).